# Drawing a 3d object on a 2D screen plane without angle of view

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a problem, I need to draw a 3D object in such a way that I can move it along the screen plane and rotate so that the angle of view is as if I always looked at it fixedly from one point.

I use the GLM library for working with matrices. I tried to use glm::ortho, but I can not operate with the z coordinate, respectively, the model does not rotate. if i use glm::perspective, then the model looks like i need only in the center of the screen. I mean, for example, the character model is depicted in the window of a game. How would you not move the window at any point on the screen, you look at the model directly, and not as if looking out of the corner. 
I apologize, I do not know how to explain it in normal language, I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Apply the translation on the screen *after* the perspective matrix. Keep in mind that the perspective matrix produces normalized device coordinates. (ie -1 to 1)

Comment: @Botje, please can you explain? Do you mean instead of the standard multiplication of PVM(MVP matrix) to produce PMV or MPV?

Comment: No, i meant "do the translation **after** you multiply by MVP matrix".

Comment: @Botje, matrix M already contains translation. if you mean to do in the vertex shader multiply P * V * vec3(model coordinates) * M, then I only have one distorted face of the model (in my case, a cube)

Comment: @Botje, At random, I found a solution. I simply multiply the matrix M instead of the MVP, containing the translation (glm::translate), by the position of the vertex. But since, as you noted, the projection of the screen is ranged from -1 to 1, my model with a screen resolution of 800 by 600 was stretched in width, for this I had to use the scale function to adjust the model to the screen resolution, but it is still not broadcast in pixels. I think all the same in a normal way this is done by creating a projection matrix to fit the screen, but I don’t know how to do it. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Let's say you render vertex `(0,0,1)`. After multiplication by the MVP matrix (that renders the vertex head on, ie no translations, ie at the origin), you might end up with `(-0.23, 0.10, -5.7)` in NDC, so roughly to the left of the center of the screen. If you wanted to shift this vertex to the *right*, you simply add a few units to the x coordinate. for example, adding `(0.75, 0, 0)` will shift the pixel for a total of `(0.58, 0.10, -5.7)` to the far right of the screen **without changing the perspective**.

Comment: So yes, I literally meant `vec4 tempPos = mvpMatrix * pos; tempPos /= tempPos.w; gl_Position = tempPos + vec4(0.75, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: @Botje, thank you, that works.